# how to deal with Nasty unparallel tag in HTML?

Tags: python, html

I have few thousands HTML sources to read. It is from forum which started from 2004. My basic idea is to read through page by change the page number in Python script. All thing I need is like this

```
 lot of other tag from beginning
 <div id="posts">
  lot of stuff between
 </div>
 lot of other tag till ending
```

I use beautifulsoup findAll command to read the stuff between  and  which works perfectly in 99% percent time, I think. Suddenly, one page gives me frustration. And the structure is like below

```
 lot of other tag from beginning
 <div id="posts">
  first part
  </div>
  second part
 </div>
 lot of other tag till ending
```

As you can see, here is a unparallel  which has no  before. Then the beautifulsoup thought that the second last  is the ending for the  then it stopped ignoring the useful second part between the unparallel  and the real ending  for

I believe it is rare condition since I finished another thread which contains 1960 pages which has no such problem. This problem occurred in an old thread. any one has any idea? Is there any fixing tool ? It is quite frustrated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Before implement a fix, would it be faster to just process that pages manually? :)

Comment: @demalexx sorry, what do you mean manually?

Comment: you need to extract data and you wrote a script that extracts it. But in some rare cases it can't extract it automatically. Then you could extract info from that broken files manually, like in Notepad :)

Comment: @demalexx your suggestion is actually same as tony did say. Yeah. I give up and will fix the rare case MANNUALLY. THANKS LOT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oh dear.
Easiest way would be to fix the page so all end tags have a start tag....

Basically the mark up is not correct, browsers have all sorts of ifs and buts to cope with this and other fun ones like

```
<Tag1><Tag2></Tag1></Tag2>
```

to cope with the bad old days where html wasn't valid xml.
It's do able in code, though a lot of work, but basically you have to "guess" where the missing start tag should be.

In this specific case where would youy logically inset a start div, or could you afford to rip out the orphaned end tag. You have to guess the intent... Painful, very painful.

Quite liklely to make a mess of your logic. Me I'd throw an error on this page and move to the next, then get it fixed.

Comment: Man， you are right. The second last </div> is really painfully to remove. If I wanna remove it, I have to change all logic I wrote before to consider this .0000001% case.......stupid if I do that. Thanks lot!